# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_7_input to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (469,)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

Running my model produces the following error:

```
> ### ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_24_input to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (470,)
```

#### My Code:

```
# Initalizign the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))

# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

#Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

### fitting the classifier to the training set
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
```

In the last step, I am getting the error. I am new in Data Science & Neural Networks. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try changing the `input_dim=470` in the 1st Dense layer.